# What's the goal of HR departments, anyway (for a career change perspective)?

Tags: human-resources

I have a computer science background, but I always see myself as a people person, rather than a computer nerd.

I've lived in three different continents and worked with international colleagues over a decade now. I am aware of cultural differences and people management. But I never worked in an HR department before. Now, that I am looking for a new position, I came across a job post that intrigued me. Looking at the key tasks and responsibilities, I found that apart from "Build an EVP", all the other listed items are things that I used to do, when I was managing my team. I am really thinking about this career change. However, do you think my lack of professional HR experience can be a problem?

Comment: Hi OldCastle, this question is a little bit too specific to yourself and sounds like a, *"what skills should I learn/have to make the transition to HR from a computer background?"*. I don't believe it's really on topic for our site, so have added a vote to close and the community will vote if they agree or not. Could you change the question so it's not just orientated to yourself? [See here for more info](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/52713)

Comment: Were the goals not clear from the job description? The best people to answer this would be the ones from the recruitment department, who got the ob posted. We can only speculate, no guarantee of accuracy.

Comment: 5 minutes on a search engine would give you all the answers in much more detail than you'll get here. Managing a team and HR are not even close.

Comment: I can't help but point out the irony in a "people person" coming into a topic with the claim they are not "a computer nerd".

Comment: HR is a profession, and it is expected that anyone working in the field has at least a minimal level of qualification. In applying for any HR position you are going to be up against people with that training. If you've been managing a development team then any entry level HR position is going to be a significant pay cut.

Comment: What are the requirements of the position you are looking at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I run a small company that at one point was 11 people. We never had any HR staff or even an HR consultant, and there were days we really needed to have some. What HR provides to the company, and we had to muddle by without or doing for ourselves, included:

- knowing labour and to some extent tax laws and the various forms and regulations involved. (New baby? Go see HR and they'll do what needs to be done to get your with-holdings changed.)
- knowing the benefits we offered and who our vendors were (we offered extra health insurance coverage, we paid for gym memberships, etc)
- keep track of everyone's address and phone number in one place
- offer help to someone having a problem that is not "I don't know enough C++" or "I want to go to a technical conference" This could be connecting them with the free counselling we had as a benefit, or telling us that they needed an accommodation without us having to hear all the details
- recruiting
- doing firing in a legal and fair way (and all the paperwork)
- handling layoffs
- managing changes to any of the tax/hiring/workplace laws and regulations and making sure everyone knew them

They would also have been super helpful for things like pandemic lockdowns where you just know there are some best practices out there and don't need to re-invent the wheel yourself.

We muddled by with a combination of doing things ourselves, remembering things HR had done for us when we worked for big companies, and asking staff to do things themselves ("go find the form on the insurance web site and send it to them, it's best if we don't see it because it's personal" kind of thing). But it would have been great to have someone around who had the bandwidth to really know all the rules we have to operate under, and didn't have to focus on day to day goals like getting some software deployed.

As well, I remember in big companies that HR people could help you with conflict with others, be someone to whistleblow to, get harassers away from you, and even find you the place in the company that was great for you. As an undergrad on a co-op term, I did a project for someone in the huge HR department of a company with tens of thousands of people. As it wrapped up, he asked me what would be my dream job when I graduated. I told him, because I liked him. Within a month I had a letter offering me precisely that within the company. I had not realized we were doing an interview :-)

A lot of people like to diss HR. "HR is not your friend!" they say. I'm betting you like getting your paycheque, getting your benefits, getting the email about how there's a new vendor for some particular benefit now, and all of that. I also expect you appreciate that if bosses try to do things that actually violate labour law (and I know depending on where you live that not much violates labour law, but it can happen) HR stops them and says "if you do that, we could be charged" and then you get to keep some of your rights. Being an HR person can be a useful and rewarding career. Your background sounds like you'd bring some real strengths to it from the point of view of the employees of a large company, because you'd understand what they needed.

Comment: "HR stops them and says "if you do that, we could be charged" and then you get to keep some of your rights." HR is not doing that because they are your friend. HR is doing that because their job is to protect the company.

Comment: Their motivation is not of interest to me. The fact is that an employee in a company with an HR department remains somewhat less exploited, on average, than an employee in a company without one. Friend or no, they support some of the interests of the employees, namely that the bosses not exceed the limits the law allows of exploitation.

Answer (score 5):

The major roles of HR are

1. **Legal Compliance** keep track of all local and global labor laws, put internal policies into place, educated, monitor and guide internal behavior
2. **Adminstrative** handle lots of paperwork: personel files, correspondensce with third parties, etc., benefits selection and admin, vacation, leave of absence, etc.
3. **Talent acquisition** recruiting, interviewing, offering, relationship building, networking
4. **Performance management, compensation, career advancement** Define what all the job grades are, set compensation structure and policiy, set promotion guidelines and requirements, set salary ranges for the different job grades,
5. **Help dealing with the problem cases** somone good wants to leave, somewhat bad needs to be turned around or fired, someone surfs porn at work or made a mess in the kitchen, someone has a spouse with cancer.

There is a fair variety of roles here and often people specialize in a certain domains, i.e. "Talent Acquisition Specialists" typically only do recruiting work. In some cases HR also plays a crucial role in building the corporate culture but that varies a lot from one company to the next.

Items 1,2, 4 are often "set and forget", i.e. once a good framework is in place, the rest is mainly maintenance, updates and automated. Recruiting and issue handling take in many cases most of the time.

Make sure you have the stomach for #5: "dealing with the shxt shows". A lot of this can be heart wrenching on a personal level and as an HR rep you will see way more of this than you are used to. Most of this is handled discreetly and without anyone ever knowing, so most employees aren't even aware of it (as it should be) but as an HR partner you will be front and center for this type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Its more about how you can explain what you did, rather than what hr does.

For example, you mention never having built an EVP. But I bet you did, you just didn't know it.

Because as a manager, you probably focused on career development for your team, and fostering a culture of constant learning and ownership of product.
What you want to focus on is not the function of HR - because HR  has many functions, and you're not going to be able to angle yourself in as a master of any of them.

But you are going to be able to angle yourself in by showing you have a breadth of relevant skills, and an ability to lead and react to technical ppl, which is an area hr struggles with.

Your best bet is to use linked in, find ppl in the org that are related to the position (or even in your network?) and then meet or talk with them. Then you're a warm lead for the role, not a cold one.

Answer (score -1):

#### Protect the company from being sued for breaking labor law.

The basic goal of HR is to protect the company from being sued. This can take several forms: advising leadership and management staff about their requirements under the law, ensuring that hiring, firing, and employee complaints are carried out in a systematic, formalised fashion, and on occasion, helping employees who are having issues with bosses that might not be doing the right thing.

Comment: There's a lot more to HR than that.

Comment: I would suggest that the main function of HR is an *intelligence* function. Maintaining a familiarity with regulatory rules, and ensuring the firm's compliance, is one aspect. But so is pacifying industrial unrest and conflict, and developing the skill and experience to advise management on labour relations. Furthermore, membership of the HR occupation forms the basis for an informal intelligence network between employers, which in normal times will be loose and informal, but can be quickly formalised when there is a need to repress a significant organised threat from labour.

Comment: Where I work the HR team do so much more than this

Comment: I think this answer confused "the legal department" with hr.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The purpose of HR is covering the corporation's liabilities to minimize the risk of lawsuits. Lawyers don't make sure that you follow processes and procedures like HR does. For instance, in Hilmar's answer, 1,2, and 5 all fall under the umbrella of "make sure the company doesn't get sued", and 3 and 4 are all about protecting the company from discrimination claims.